# High publish latency with PubSub Golang client

Tags: go, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-sdk

We have a custom Golang script to publish messages to PubSub.

```
client, err := pubsub.NewClient(ctx, GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT))
```

We then use the same client to publish to upto 40 topics.

```
topic1 := client.Topic(topicName)
    topic1.PublishSettings = pubsub.PublishSettings{
        DelayThreshold: 10 * time.Millisecond,
        CountThreshold: 1000,
        NumGoroutines:  70 * runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0),
        ByteThreshold:  1e6,
        Timeout:        60 * time.Second,
    }



topic2 := client.Topic(topicName)
    topic2.PublishSettings = pubsub.PublishSettings{
        DelayThreshold: 10 * time.Millisecond,
        CountThreshold: 1000,
        NumGoroutines:  70 * runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0),
        ByteThreshold:  1e6,
        Timeout:        60 * time.Second,
    }
.
.
.
```

and then based on a certain condition publish to 1 of the topic.  Our publisher loop looks like this

```
semaphore := make(chan int, 3000)
for i := 0; i < totalMessages; i++ {
            semaphore <- 1
            go func(topic *pubsub.Topic, semaphore chan int) {
                data := []byte(_RandStringBytes(messageLengthInBytes))
                msg := &pubsub.Message{
                    Data: data,
                }
                if _, err := topic.Publish(ctx, msg).Get(ctx); err != nil {
                    log.Fatalf("Could not publish message: %v", err)
                }
                <-semaphore
            }(topic, semaphore)
        }
```

We use 3000 Goroutines to publish messages to the topics and synchronously wait for messages to get acknowledged, that means there are at a time only 3000 in flight/waiting for acknowledgement at client.

Our current rate of publishing is close to 5K RPS but our latencies are as high as 30 seconds.

Below are the stats that I compiled from our Datadog dashboard.

```
Publish Latency.    Number of Messages
0-1                 1877
1-2                 1990
2-3                 2661
2-3                 2149
5-10                10323
10-15               4013
15-20               10322
20-25               3034
25-30               925
> 30                1901
```

**When I wrote a small benchmark script to publish messages to a single topic the average latency was 147ms from the same machine.**

I've tried to tweak the publisher settings for each topic but that did not help.

**Now I have couple of question.**

1. Is is the right way to use a single client instance to publish to multiple topics ?
2. Is there some built in construct in the library to support such fanout scenarios ?

Comment: How are you measuring the latency? It would be useful to know where you are instrumenting the code to determine the publish latency. Does the timer start right before the `Publish` call and end right after it?

Comment: Yes the timer starts before Publish and ends just right after it .

Answer (score 0):

did u try bulk publish?

publish(topic,[]Message{1,2,3,4,.....})

Comment: No, I did not I'll try to implement that and come back with results.

Comment: @kaysush and the code your attached is not good enough, you should make sure ` <-semaphore` release correctly. like what if panic?

Comment: Yes, this is a quick and dirty test script code not the production one. I just wanted to show the general template of how the production code looks like without all the bells and whistle.